# APIM not clearing the cache after specified duration

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to write a cache store policy onto my apim. But for some reason, the cache is not clearing or dropped after the mentioned duration.
Below is my code snippet.
[Code snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyUK0.png)

I have a header with bearer token authorization and query parameter as emailid.
Can someone help to understand why the cache is not dropped after the time?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Setup unique key -->
        <!-- store and retrieve cache -->
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" must-revalidate="true" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="external" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <cache-store duration="30" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used your policy but changed `caching-type="external"` to `caching-type="internal"` and I am able to see that caching is stopped after the given period.

**`APIM Policy`**

```
<policies>
<inbound>
<base  />
<cache-lookup  vary-by-developer="false"  vary-by-developer-groups="false"  allow-private-response-caching="true"  must-revalidate="true"  downstream-caching-type="none"  caching-type="internal"  />
</inbound>
<backend>
<base  />
</backend>
<outbound>
<base  />
<cache-store  duration="30"  />
</outbound>
<on-error>
<base  />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

> **the cache is not clearing or dropped**

In order to clear the cache value, you can use `cache-remove-value` policy. Refer [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/cache-remove-value-policy) to know about this policy.

After 30 sec, check the **Trace** to find out whether caching is dropped or not.

[image]

**Please note** when it is caching, you will get the message in Trace as `message: cache lookup resulted in a hit`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since I am using the cache-lookup and cache-store, I don't know the key to give in the cache-remove-value.